# 2010 Chevy HHR jerking

Tags: engine, chevrolet, lights, scheduled-maintenance, hhr

Hi I just got a 2010 HHR. I drove it for about 3-4 months and the check engine light came on so I figured that it needed an oil change? It ended up turning the light off for about 3 days, then it came back on. Whenever the car is slowing itself down (without me pushing on the breaks), it jerks forward. That doesn't happen often. When I'm at a stop light it does the same thing but much harder. The jerking doesn't happen all the time but the check engin light has been on for about 3 months. I haven't had the money lately to go to the mechanic. Please give me some ideas.

I tried doing the code at autozone and they say some cap might be loose. It doesn't make since ... If the car is jerking

Comment: Hello Julie and welcome to the site! To help us diagnose this, it would be really helpful to know exactly what code Auto Zone pulled from your car. Also how many miles on your hhr? Btw, if you have a smart phone,  you can get a $15 or less blue tooth adapter for your cars OBD-II (On Board Diagnostics version 2) interface. You can also get a very cheap or free app (I recommend Torque) to talk to it.  This will let you pull codes, reset them,  or just pull emgine data from your car.  Very cheap and a huge help in funding problems like this.

Comment: When you say it jerks when you're slowing down or at a stop, does it try to lurch forward? Does the engine rev up or bog down when it lurches? When you're at a stop and it lurches, do you have to press the brake extra hard to keep the car from rolling forward? If you don't, could you classify the lurching as more of a rough vibration? Are there any noises that coincide with the lurching? PS Welcome to the site! You've provided a good starting point, we should be able to narrow it down with a little more information!

Comment: You need to pull codes from the computer before it can be diagnosed.

Comment: Sounds roughly like a P0455 from the Autozone genius, which would have nothing to do with the vehicle jerking.

Comment: Maybe a loose motor or tranny mount. While the car if OFF and parked, on the outside of it, bounce it up and down by hand as hard as you can and get some people to help and get it to bounce and listen for metal to metal noises and that could indicate a bushing in some mount, etc. has work out and that may mean there more play than there needs to be in whatever part the bushing is worn out in the mounting bracket. Sometimes doing the bounce with the hood SECURELY opened may give you a visual if there's a mount on the top you can see easily or hear noise coming from it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the loose cap but check your fuel cap to ensure it fits properly and snug and is not loose. Sometimes the cap being off or not sealing on some cars can cause codes and maybe slight engine performance issues.